# eslint error '$localize' is seen as "Unsafe assignment of an `any` value"

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint

eslint sees all usage of $localize as errors, returning two errors. `Unsafe assignment of an 'any' value` and `Unsafe any typed template tag`.

The weird thing about the problem is that i am the only one have this problem. The others on the project does not experience this. This happens on both my machines.

So far we have tried deleting VS code and all plugins, and reinstalling, with everything the same as my colleagues, then it works for a while and after a few days/weeks, the problem show itself again. We have even done a full wipe of a the pc once, and still after som time the problem shows itself again.

Have also tried to set localize as readonly in `.eslintrc.json`

```
"globals": {
    "$localize": "readonly"
},
```

So far i have yet to find anyone else with this problem.

Comment: Can't it be related to folder structure? How did you open the project? I have had one issue with ESLint once, when I opened cloned repo's top folder instead of subfolder that actually contained the Angular project. In that case eslint always reported the error. Can you please try it?

Comment: Sadly, this is not the problem. The open folder is my angular folder. Just tried to close it and open it again, jeg to make sure it was not the problem.

Comment: Does command "npx eslint yourProjectDirectory" find an error or is it just VsCode showing error?

Comment: This problem happens both for the VS Code ESlint extension and when running "ng lint", have not tried "npx eslint yourProjectDirectory"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the problem was that I used the wrong `tsconfig` file in the eslint parserOptions.
Switching tsconfig.json with tsconfig.app.json made everything work like expected:

```json
...
"parserOptions": {
    project": [
        "tsconfig.app.json" // <-- Instead of "tsconfig.json"
    ],
    "createDefaultProgram": true
},
...
```